# How to fetch server configuration stored in yaml format using global variables for 10 projects?

Tags: yaml

How to fetch server configuration stored in yaml format using global variables for 10 projects ?

Comment: We need some specifics to answer that

Comment: I came across this question during an interview. I am afraid, I dont have any other info.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't suited for such questions

Comment: I'd advise to convert this to a tangible example and try doing that by yourself. If you couldn't, come back with a code snippet and a more concrete question